# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac: Error when restoring or adding Nuget packages

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I have a problem with adding and restoring nuget packages in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. When I try to add a package, I get an error like this:

```
Getting restore information for project /Users/maksym/Desktop/Projects/klosterfrau/Klosterfrau/Klosterfrau.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/maksym/Desktop/Projects/klosterfrau/Klosterfrau.iOS/Klosterfrau.iOS.csproj
Getting restore information for project /Users/maksym/Desktop/Projects/klosterfrau/Klosterfrau.Android/Klosterfrau.Android.csproj
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

And the same error when I try to restore packages. But project builds just fine (Xamarin, by the way). Rider fro JetBrains adds them just fine, but I don't like that there build takes twice as long, so I prefer Visual Studio. I tried to google my issue, but IDE is very new and I found nothing. Thanks

Comment: Did you update the version of Net that is being used?  the nuget package may need to get recompiled with new version of Net.  When Net gets updated the dependencies in the compiler do not recognize a change in Net versions.  So yo may need to force the nuget packages to recompile with newer version of Net.  I usually make copy of bin folder in all projects and then delete bin which will force all code to recompile.

Comment: @jdweng I installed Xamarin SDK a few days ago, so everything is new and fresh. And problem is clearly with Visual studio, cause Rider updates and installs packages just fine

Comment: What version of Net is Xamarin using?

Comment: VS for Mac uses Mono, not .NET Core and obviously not the Windows .NET Framework, but as jdweng suggests, make sure you're using an up-to-date Mono. If the problem persists, try downloading nuget.exe from nuget.org/downloads. VS4M 2019 should bundle NuGet 4.8. Once you have a nuget.exe run "mono nuget.exe restore -verbosity detailed" and see if you get more info on the crash. I work on NuGet, but without a repro I can run myself, or more detailed info on where the crash happened, I can't help.

Comment: @zivkan I installed the latest version of Mono framework, problem still exists. What nuget.exe are you talking about? I am working on a mac

Comment: it would be interesting to try nuget.exe 4.8, which should match the version that comes with mono and VS4M, but also download and test nuget.exe 5.0 to see if the bug has already been fixed. As I said earlier, you download them from https://www.nuget.org/downloads. Despite the exe extension, it's a managed assembly that you run with mono (on Windows you can run it like any other command line exe)

Comment: @zivkan I tried it, it opened in Xamarin Profiler and still nuget packages are not restoring and not adding

Comment: what about restoring with nuget.exe from the command line (run with mono)? If it fails with nuget.exe, you need to report it to the NuGet team. If it works with nuget.exe, you need to report it to Xamarin/VS4M team. I'm sure the Xamarin people would also like a sample solution, but if you report it to NuGet, it would be extremely useful to give us a sample solution because we don't use Macs, so if you only write steps to reproduce the problem, it's less likely we'll be able to reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: @zivkan if I restore via terminal command nuget restore, it works fine, there is something going on with Visual Studio specifically

Comment: Then I recommend [reporting a problem though vsfm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2019)

Comment: @zivkan thanks, I will try to do that than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering - I reported this issue to Microsoft and they responded that this is a known bug, and I just needed to install Android SDK. They are going to fix that issue in the future, but for now I installed the SDK and everything works fine